# Радиальный бэкграунд (radial mean, radial median) Python

Tags: python-3.x, изображения, filter

имеется следующая общая задача: необходимо реализовать фильтр вычитания радиального среднего и радиальной медианы. Что имеется в виду: есть данные рентгенограммы с примененной геометрией детектора. Данные рентгенограммы это интенсивности отражения от решеток изучаемого объекта. Имеется иногда шум, от которого стандартно избавляются в таких случаях. Каким образом - берут координаты пикселей из геометрии, берут данные интенсивности из h5 файла. Сами данные уже отцентрированы. Рассчитываются радиусы - получается определенный набор, для каждого бина рассчитывается среднее значение и медианы, и все интенсивности для каждого своего радиуса заменяются посчитанным средним или медианой для этого же радиуса.

[image: геометрия]

вот так выглядит картинка геометрии, тут нет интенсивностей, поэтому картинка среднего и медианы должна быть плоской
[image: верная радиальная картинка]
это вот среднее (radial mean) для данной картинки (посчитано в другой программе)

У меня же с помощью следующей функции получается другой результат (проблема в конце)

```
def radial_symetry(background, rs = None, is_fft_shifted = True):
    if rs is None :
        i = np.fft.fftfreq(background.shape[0]) * background.shape[0]
        j = np.fft.fftfreq(background.shape[1]) * background.shape[1]
        k = np.fft.fftfreq(background.shape[2]) * background.shape[2]
        i, j, k = np.meshgrid(i, j, k, indexing='ij')
        rs      = np.sqrt(i**2 + j**2 + k**2).astype(np.int16)

        if is_fft_shifted is False :
            rs = np.fft.fftshift(rs)
        rs = rs.ravel()

    ########### Find the radial average
    # get the r histogram
    r_hist = np.bincount(rs)
    # get the radial total 
    r_av = np.bincount(rs, background.ravel())
    # prevent divide by zero
    nonzero = np.where(r_hist != 0)
    zero    = np.where(r_hist == 0)
    # get the average
    r_av[nonzero] = r_av[nonzero] / r_hist[nonzero].astype(r_av.dtype)
    r_av[zero]    = 0

    ########### Make a large background filled with the radial average
    background = r_av[rs].reshape(background.shape)
    return background, rs, r_av
```

[image: mymean]

для медианы (radial median) имеется следующее

```
def av_median_radial_profile(x, y, dist, data, mask_inp = None, pol_bool = False):

    # x,y,z from geometry file
    r = np.hypot(x,y)
    r = r.astype(np.int)
    r = r.ravel()


    # I from data image
    data1 = (data.ravel()).copy()
    data1 = data1.astype(np.float)

    # mask_inp - MASK_GOOD and MASK_BAD
    # Check with mask => indices where MASK_BAD, I[indices] = np.nan

    if mask_inp is not None:
        mask = mask_inp.copy()
        mask = mask.ravel()
        false_mask = np.where(mask == False)
        data1[false_mask] = np.nan

    if pol_bool: 

        #Make correction to polarisation if get distance from .h5 file
        z = np.ones_like(x.flatten()) * dist

        # calculate polarisation factor
        pol = PolarisationFactorDet(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z, degree = 0.99)

        # Take into account polarisation
        data1 = data1 * pol

    else:
        print('No polarisation factor')

    # Calculate median <I>

    b = len(set(r))
    median_radialprofile = stats.binned_statistic(r, data1, 
                                                  statistic = lambda q: np.nanmedian(q).astype(np.int),
                                                  bins = b)[0]  

    plt.plot(median_radialprofile)
    plt.savefig('median_stats_binned_not_pol.png')
    plt.close()

    set_r = list(set(r)) # get the list of r without duplication
    set_r.sort()

    max_r = max(set_r) # determine the maximum r

    median_r = np.array([0.]*len(r.flatten())) # array of median I for each r
    m_curve = np.array([0.]*len(set_r))


    for j in set_r:
        result = np.where(r.flatten() == j)[0]
        med_v = np.median(data1[result])
        median_r[result] += med_v
        m_curve[set_r.index(j)] += med_v



    med_background = median_r.reshape(data.shape)

    plt.plot(m_curve)
    plt.savefig('median_not_pol.png')
    plt.close()

    #med_background = median_radialprofile[r].reshape(data.shape)


    # Substract I = I - <I>
    m_background = data.copy() - med_background

    return m_background
```

[image: median]

тут ситуация еще хуже
потому что медиану можно посчитать вот так

```
median_radialprofile = stats.binned_statistic(r, data1,statistic = lambda q: np.nanmedian(q).astype(np.int),bins = b)[0]
```

но если сделать

```
med_background = median_radialprofile[r].reshape(data.shape)
```

он выдает ошибку с размерностью
и поэтому там есть реализация через цикл
есть фильтр медианы встроенный, но это не тот, что мне нужен(потому что он центровой элемент заменяет медианой посчитанный вокруг него), а мне нужно медианой значений, посчитанных для каждого конкретного радиуса).

Никак не могу разобраться в чем проблема.